# Initial view controller in Container View Controller not being shown

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I watched the WWDC video on UIViewController Containment and read through this blog post: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/04/containing-viewcontrollers/

but I can't get my initial view controller to show.  Is there something I am missing?  In my ContainerViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    _homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
    _detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];

    [self setSubViewControllers:@[_homeViewController, _detailViewController]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (_selectedViewController.parentViewController == self) {
        // nothing to do
        return;
    }

    // adjust the frame to fit the container view
    _selectedViewController.view.frame = _containerView.bounds;

    // make sure that it resizes on rotation automatically
    _selectedViewController.view.autoresizingMask = _containerView.autoresizingMask;

    // add as child VC
    [self addChildViewController:_selectedViewController];

    // add it to container view, calls willMoveToParentViewController for us
    [_containerView addSubview:_selectedViewController.view];

    // notify that move is done
    [_selectedViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

- (void)loadView {
    // set up the base view
    CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    aView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    // set up content view
    _containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    _containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    _containerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [aView addSubview:_containerView];

    self.view = aView;
}

- (void)setSubViewControllers:(NSArray *)subViewControllers {
    _subViewControllers = [subViewControllers copy];

    if (_selectedViewController) {
        // remove previous VC
    }

    _selectedViewController = _subViewControllers[0];

}
```

My ContainerViewController is the initial view controller in my storyboard.  I see that it shows on the simulator, but the HomeViewController (the first child view controller in my container) does not show.

When I step through the debugger, the subViewControllers property of my ContainerViewController does have the homeViewController and detailViewController in it.  The viewDidLoad of HomeViewController also does get called.  I just don't see anything on screen except the background color of the ContainerViewController.

Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have an NSArray, but you are trying to access it as a C array.

```
_subViewControllers[0]
```

should be:

```
[_subViewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

That being said, you seem to have some code that could be better in other methods.  I would personally clean this up a lot and make it much simpler.  I would remove loadView and _containerView, and just use self.view as one normally would.  For what you are trying to do, there really doesn't even seem a need to track parent and child view controllers.  Anyway, this is how I would do it:

```
@interface ContainerViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *subViewControllers;
@end

@implementation ObservationReportViewController {
    UIViewController *_selectedViewController;
}
@synthesize subViewControllers = _subViewControllers;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        HomeViewController *homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
        homeViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
        detailViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

        // Retain the view controllers.
        self.subViewControllers = @[homeViewController, detailViewController];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setSelectedViewController: [_subViewControllers objectAtIndex:0]];
}

-(void)setSelectedViewController:(UIViewController *)selectedViewController {
    if (_selectedViewController != selectedViewController) {
        [_selectedViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        _selectedViewController = selectedViewController;
        // adjust the frame to fit the container view
        [self.view addSubview:_selectedViewController.view];
        //_selectedViewController.view.frame = _containerView.bounds;
        _selectedViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    }
}
```

Comment: The [0] isn't a problem in iOS 6.  I tried what you suggested but it still doesn't show the HomeViewController.  Not sure why still...

Comment: @Crystal I had a typo in the last line.  Just fixed it.  You might want to make sure the init method I provided is being called, instead of just `init()`.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not the brightest person in the world, but the reason nothing was being shown on the screen was because the nibs were in the storyboard and I needed to do this instead:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];
    _homeViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
    _detailViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
```

Hopefully this helps someone who is also not familiar with Storyboards yet.

Comment: I don't know if you're doing it this way for educational purposes, but this can be done with almost no code by using container views in the storyboard.

Comment: @Crystal When posting here, it will always be helpful to say if you are using storyboards and also if you are using ARC.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the InitialViewController through the storyboard in a different storyb than the MainStoryboard, then you need to update the project settings to use that new storyboard.

[image]

Go to project settings, General and set the Main Interface setting to the new storyboard

[image]